# Filter an object which contains values of zero

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having a little bit of trouble of trying to filter out data that does not contain zero.

for example:

```
const height = {
  cm: 0,
  feet: 10,
  inches: 5,
}
```

and the desired result is to remove elements that dont have zero.

so desired result is:

```
const height = {
  feet: 10,
  inches: 5,
}
```

i have tried

```
    const boo = Object.keys(height).filter((e) => height[e] > 0);
```

but no luck.

ANy ideas

Comment: You’re filtering the object keys and not the object itself.

Comment: do you need to keep the same object reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the entries and delete unwanted keys.

```js
const height = { cm: 0, feet: 10, inches: 5 };

Object.entries(height).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v === 0) delete height[k];
});

console.log(height);
```

Another approach creates a new object without unwanted parts.

```js
const
    height = { cm: 0, feet: 10, inches: 5 },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(height)
        .filter(([k, v]) => v !== 0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(height).forEach(key => {
    if (height[key] === 0) {
        delete height[key]
    }
})
```